# Honeywell HZ432 showing heat when cooling and cool when heating

Tags: hvac

First off...The system is heating when I call for heat and cooling when I call for cooling. so it seems to be functioning perfectly. The problem lies in the panel indicators. They show the exact opposite of what is actually happening. The problem started when we replaced the system with a B type system and the technician changed the two Nest thermostats from O to B. If I change the Advanced Config on the HZ432 from O to B for each zone, the system runs A/C when calling for heat and vice-a-versa.

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: What make and model are your heat pump and air handler/furnace?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You gotta switch your wire (orange) on the board to b or o in the equipment section. Just happened to me today it was a pain.